# How do I remove Blank Space from File Names

Tags: powershell, filenames

I am trying to remove blank spaces from many file names using PowerShell 3.0. Here is the code that I am working with:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowershellTests\With_Space"
Copy-Item $Files.FullName -Destination C:\PowershellTests\Without_Space
Set-Location -Path C:\PowershellTests\Without_Space
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }
```

For example: the With_Space directory has these files:

```
Cable Report 3413109.pdf
Control List 3.txt
Test Result Phase 2.doc
```

The Without_Space directory will need the above file name to be:

```
CableReport3413109.pdf
ControlList3.txt
TestResultPhase 2.doc
```

Currently, the script shows no error but it only copies the source files to the destination folder, but doesn't remove the spaces in file names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code should work just fine, but since `Get-ChildItem *.txt` lists only .txt files the last statement should remove the spaces from just the text files, giving you a result like this:

> Cable Report 3413109.pdf
>   ControlList3.txt
>   Test Result Phase 2.doc

This should remove spaces from the names of all files in the folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 use this to restrict processing to just files:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }
```

Comment: for double space in filename (file  name.txt) doesn't work. why?

Comment: @user2284877 I have no idea what you're talking about. The replacement works just fine even for multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: look here: http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=42035.0  when I  add -rename, works only for one space in filename. not for multiple consecutive. ....$sNewName = (Get-Item $file).BaseName -replace ' ','')...

Comment: @user2284877 Again, that is not how the `-replace` operator works. Please post a new question with a [mcve] describing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

something like this could work

```
$source = 'C:\temp\new'
$dest = 'C:\temp\new1'
Get-ChildItem $source | % {copy $_.FullName $(join-path $dest ($_.name -replace ' '))}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I will check out the code you've written. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think your script should almost work, except `$_` isn't going to be defined as anything. By using the for-each cmdlet (`%`), you assign it and then can use it.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | %{Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.Name -replace ' ','' )}
```

EDIT:
That interpretation was totally wrong. Some people seem to have found it useful, but as soon as you have something being piped, it appears that `$_` references the object currently in the pipe. My bad.

Comment: The current object variable (`$_`) works just fine in the given context. Running `Rename-Item` in a `ForEach-Object` loop is not required.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers! I had tried replacing Rename-Item with echo to see what was going on, and the false conclusions proceeded from there.

Comment: Thanks Jared and Ansgar, it worked! I appreciate your help.